# 2,000+ jQuery UI autocomplete combobox throws stopped responding error

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete, combobox

Just wanting to confirm that I've exceeded the the practical limitation of the jQuery UI autocomplete combobox, I get the following error in FF:

> A script on this page may be busy, or
>   it may have stopped responding. You
>   can stop the script now, open the
>   script in the debugger, or let the
>   script continue.

The page is a big table (2000+ rows) generated from php, it was going to contain 7 of these combo boxes (7 columns) per row, however I can barely get through the first column of the set.  The page will load and function but it takes several minutes and the browser becomes non-responsive for a while.

Is there perhaps a way to alter the JS to make it more efficient?  Below is a sample of the JS, I'm using php to insert the array into the script (line 3).

Code:

```
            <script type='text/javascript'>
  var input = new Array();
var i = 1;
<?php echo $JSElements; ?> //PHP
$('.TC_1').each(function(index) {

input[i] = $("[name=TC_"+i+"_1]").autocomplete({
    source: elementArray,
    select: function(){alert("selected");},
    minLength: 0
}).addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left");

//Get the id for the target field:
    var target = $(input[i]).attr('name');
    var ID = target.substr(3);

$("<button id='bt_"+ID+"' type='button'>&nbsp;</button>")
    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
    .insertAfter(input[i])
    .button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
        },
        text: false
    })
    .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
    .addClass("ui-corner-right ui-button-icon")
    .click(function() {

        // close if already visible
        if ($("[name=TC_"+ID+"]").autocomplete("widget").is(":visible")) {
        $("[name=TC_"+ID+"]").autocomplete( "close" );
             return;
        }
        $(this).blur();
        $("[name=TC_"+ID+"]").autocomplete("search", "" );
        $("[name=TC_"+ID+"]").focus();
    });
    i++;
});
  </script>
```

If there isn't a way to get this working? can anyone suggest any alternatives?  Keep in mind that there will be likely by about 8,000 fields!  If not, my last resort is custom building a simple ajax dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the jQuery autocomplete plugin will actually accept a URL, making Ajaxy goodness very simple to get up and running.

[See here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions)

Comment: Yeah I figured, but you don't think that the sheer quantity of these guys I'm trying to create is causing the sloooooow load time?  The way I have it working is it is iterating through the text fields, converting them to the comboboxes and creating a unique corresponding button.

Comment: But the advantage of the ajax version is that you can filter the results on the server side before you send them down to the browser. When the ajax call is made it will pass the current contents of the text box on the querystring so you can cull the vast majority of the results. This is assuming the performance issue is not already on the server side ;-)